# Getting the Product Inventory Control Grid info through an SQL export on Volusion

Tags: sql, volusion

Is it possible to export the information for a Product's Inventory Control Grid? The Inventory Control Grid is a table at the bottom of a product page that shows what options on the product are connected to other products. This information I can't find anywhere else on volusion, and there doesn't seem to be an obvious way to export the information contained in it from the whole site. Here is an example of what it looks like:

[image: Inventory Control Grid on Volusion.com]

I will have to resort to curl, which would take a very long time process to complete, if there is no way to export this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This info is in the KITS and KITLNKS tables (within Standard Export).

Answer (score 0):

I've successfully exported this information by using the api to query the products table specifying the IsChildOfProductCode field to the ProductCode of the parent product.  Here's a sample post:

> &API_Name=Generic\Products&SELECT_Columns=p.ProductCode,p.ProductID,p.ProductName,p.StockStatus&WHERE_Column=p.IsChildOfProductCode&WHERE_Value=***YourVolusionProductCode***

Comment: Does that include the information about what options each child product is attached to?